# Python regex search for string at beginning of line in file

Tags: python, regex, file-io

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import io
import re
f = open('/etc/ssh/sshd_config','r')
strings = re.search(r'.*IgnoreR.*', f.read())
print(strings)
```

That returns data, but I need specific regex matching:  e.g.:

```
^\s*[^#]*IgnoreRhosts\s+yes
```

If I change my code to simply:

```
strings = re.search(r'^IgnoreR.*', f.read())
```

or even

```
strings = re.search(r'^.*IgnoreR.*', f.read())
```

I don't get anything back.  I need to be able to use real regex's like in perl

Comment: And why are you not using `re.search(r"^\s*[^#]*IgnoreRhosts\s+yes", f.read())`?

Comment: Python's regex syntax is the same as perl's

Comment: If ^Ign doesn't work, then there's no way r'^\s*[^#]*IgnoreRhosts\s+yes' would work.  I was looking for the lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the multiline mode then ^ match the beginning of a line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import io
import re
f = open('/etc/ssh/sshd_config','r')

strings = re.search(r"^\s*[^#]*IgnoreRhosts\s+yes", f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(strings.group(0))
```

Note that without this mode you can always replace `^` by `\n`

Note too that this file is calibrated as a tomato thus:

```
^IgnoreRhosts\s+yes
```

is good enough for checking the parameter

---

EDIT: a better way

```
with open('/etc/ssh/sshd_config') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('IgnoreRhosts yes'):
            print(line)
```

One more time there is no reason to have leading spaces. However if you want to be sure you can always use `lstrip()`.

Comment: What do you mean it's calibrated like a tomato?

Comment: OK, multiline was the magic. `strings = re.findall(r"^\s*    [^#]*IgnoreRhosts\s+yes", f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)
for item in strings:
print(item)`

Comment: "calibrated like a tomato"? Where does this come from?